# Access a namespaced getter function in a middleware in nuxtjs

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a store module called store/auth.js in that I have a getter

```
export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated(state) {
     return state.token != null
  }
}
```

Now I want to call this namespaced getter in my middleware. How would I go about calling that getter?

This seems to work but even without namespacing anything ...

```
export default function (context) {
  if(!context.store.getters.isAuthenticated)
    context.redirect('/')
  }
}
```

Do the getters behave differently than an action or mutation where I have to call `auth/`?

```
context.store.dispatch("auth/SomeVuexAction")
```

Comment: in your middleware, can you try import store directlly inside your export. Some thing like this: export default ({store}) => { 
console.log(store.state)
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access vuex getters as below:

```
context.store.getters["modulename/gettername"]
i.e.(In your case) mention correct module and getter name
context.store.getters["auth/isAuthenticated"]
```

Comment: I had tried it like this, but it did not work at the time. But after restarting the dev environment it looks like it works fine now...